# Keyboard shortcut to open Safari bookmark in new tab

Tags: keyboard, safari

I know that in Safari you can:

- Option-Command-# to open a bookmark in the same tab, or
- Command-Click a bookmark in the favorites bar to open it in a new tab.

But is there a way to open a bookmark in a new tab with a single keyboard shortcut?

In other words, a shortcut like Option-Command-#, with the difference being that it opens the bookmark in a new tab.

Comment: In order to open bookmark one must navigate to said bookmark. For that reason clarifying from which point of the workflow 'single keyboard shortcut' should be applied would be beneficial.

Comment: I hope my clarification helps.

Comment: Isin't opening new tab with ⌘+T before using ⌥+⌘+[1..9] easy enough?

Comment: It's alright, but somewhat annoying if you do it frequently. But I take it it's not possible then?

Comment: I wouldn't say it is impossible. I believe that there is possibility for some Automator/AppleScript to open specific webpage triggered by keyboard shortcut. But for me simplest and most effective is Spotlight. Requires maybe few keystrokes more but just delivers result I want.

Comment: Thank you. I might look into AppleScript then.